# How to add data values in linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm working with Linked List in Java. I'm trying to get the value I store in a node (AB) and add it to the value I store in another node (BC). I have so far successfully stored the values in the linked list. Now I would like to retrieve the *int* data and assign them to a variable and add those variables together.
for example  ABC = AB + BC.

code for TrainRouteList:

```
public class TrainRouteList {


Node head;
Node tail;

public void add(Node node){

    if (tail == null){
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    tail.next = node;
    tail = node;
}}
```

code for testing class:

```
public class LinkedListTest {
@Test
public void test (){
   TrainRouteList list = new TrainRouteList();

    list.add(new Node(new int[5], new String("AB")));//AB5
    list.add(new Node(new int[4], new String("BC")));//BC4
    list.add(new Node(new int[8], new String("CD")));//CD8
    list.add(new Node(new int[8], new String("DC")));//DC8
    list.add(new Node(new int[6], new String("DE")));//DE6
    list.add(new Node(new int[5], new String("AD")));//AD5
    list.add(new Node(new int[2], new String("CE")));//CE2
    list.add(new Node(new int[3], new String("EB")));//EB3
    list.add(new Node(new int[7], new String("AE")));//AE7
} }
```

Comment: What is the code for `TrainRouteList`?

Comment: What are `Node` and `TrainRouteList`? What did you try ?

Comment: ... and why `new String("aString")`?

Comment: The code for TranRouteList:

public class TrainRouteList {
  

    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public void add(Node node){

        if (tail == null){
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        }

        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;
    }
}

Comment: new int[5] gives you an array for 5 int entries. After the new the values of these 5 entries are completely undefined, they can be anything.

Comment: Not clear what you want to to. "for example take ABC": Is ABC a search term by which you find your first two entries (AB5 and BC4)? And what exactly you want to "add together"? Do you mean "sum"?

Comment: I guess your linked list implementation won't work. Why not just using the java built in LinkedList? Latter works perfectly!

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the sum of head + sum of head.next and store that in a variable called ABC. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have your `TrainRouteList` object structured. Typically for a linked list you have a pointer to the root of the list:

```
Node currNode = TrainRouteList.getRoot();
```

Then using this root, you can traverse the linked list:

```
int globalInt = 0;
while(currNode != null)
{
   if(currNode.getStr().equalsIgnoreCase("ab"))
   {
     globalInt += currNode.getVal();
   }
   else if(currNode.getStr().equalsIgnoreCase("bc"))
   {
     globalInt += currNode.getVal();
   }
   else
   {
     currNode = currNode.getChild();
   }
}
```

Again, this is dependent on how you have your Linked List set up:

Root -> Child of Root -> Child of the Child of Root -> etc.

Also note that if you have a lot of data, you can improve efficiency by using a Tree-like data structure.

*Ossss*

Based on your implementation of the TrainRouteList class, it may be easier for you to modify it this way:

```
public class TrainRouteList{

    private Node root;

    public TrainRouteList(Node root)
    {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node getRoot(){
        return this.root;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node r)
    {
       this.root = r;
    }
}
```

You should establish the relationship between the Nodes directly in the Node class.

```
public class Node{

    private int val = 0;
    private String str;
    private Node child = null;

    public Node(int val, String strVal)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.str = strVal;
    }

    //Getter + setter for object properties
    public void setVal(int val)     {this.val = val};
    public int getVal()             {return this.val};
    public void setStr(String str)  {this.str = str;}
    public String getStrt()         {return this.str;}

    //Getter + Setter for child node
    public void setChild(Node c)    {this.child = c;}
    public Node getChild()          {return this.child}
}
```

With this, you have made things more cohesive and easier to work with in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I went back through the code and I saw my mistakes with the clues from the comments thanks everyone for chiming in. The first was in my .add() I was adding an array to the Node not a int value. The second was I was storing a string in the Node with the int data. Since I know the position of each node there is no need to store a string with the int (I'm not sure if a string and an int can be store in the same node.) Then I assigned the position to a variable, so I didn't need a store a string in the node.

```
public class LinkedListTest {



@Test
public void test (){
   TrainRouteList list = new TrainRouteList();

    list.add(new Node(5));//AB5
    list.add(new Node(4));//BC4
    list.add(new Node(8));//CD8
    list.add(new Node(8));//DC8
    list.add(new Node(6));//DE6
    list.add(new Node(5));//AD5
    list.add(new Node(2));//CE2
    list.add(new Node(3));//EB3
    list.add(new Node(7));//AE7

    //
    int AB = list.head.data;
    int BC = list.head.next.data;
    int ABC = AB + BC;

    System.out.println("The Distance of A-B-C is " + ABC);


}}
```